# Excel Splicer in standalone pivot chart

Tags: excel

A quick question about Excel: is there a way to place a pivot chart slicer (time or otherwise) in a sheet that has a standalone pivot chart?
I need to filter the chart from another field in the data model, and not any field in the chart, so I use the slicers.

The only thing I get when I paste the splicer is an image (not a working window).

I have looked some around, and no example shows anything relate to this, in particular.

For PowerView, I don't have the Excel version to support it (neither can I get one), so it's not an option.

Thanks. Best regards.

[EDIT]

Corrected "splicer" to slicer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In English Excel these things are called "slicers". You can move a slicer to a different sheet with a cut and paste operation. Slicers can only live on worksheets, not on chart sheets. If your chart is on a chart sheet, move it to a regular worksheet and adjust the formatting and size to suit your needs.

Comment: Post edited to correct english (don't know why did I come up with that splicer thing). There is always a chance to do a activeX&VBA workaround, but I was trying to avoid that. Thanks.